# how to retrieve Json arrray

Tags: android, json, arrays

I tried to retrieve  lat,lng value from this json but I couldn't anyone help me to retrieve it.

Thanks in advance.

```
{
    response: {
        Success: "1",
        lat: [
            "2",
            "3"
        ],
        lon: [
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: also, this is not a valid json

Comment: I retrieved the value by done the following things

ArrayList<String> lat=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> lng=new ArrayList<String>();
jasonparser jp = new jasonparser();
j = jp.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JSONObject jobj = j.getJSONObject("response");    String success=jobj.getString("Success");    if(success.equals("1"))
{
JSONArray results = jobj.getJSONArray("lat");
for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
lat.add(result.getString(i);
}
JSONArray res=jobj.getJSONArray("lng");
for(int j=0;j<res.length;j++){
lng.add(res.getString(j);
}
}

Answer (score 2):

```
 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(yourString);
 JSONArray latitude= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("lat");

for (int i=0; i<latitude.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject lat= latitude.getJSONObject(i);
}
```